# Load electron atom app inside of another electron app

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, electron

I discover new frameworks for developing desktop apps. I found electron atom and it looks very well and matured. But I have one qustion:

Is it possible to host different electron apps in one big electron app?

in our .NET applications we have a "global framework" Form, which loads different applications in frames. But every application can runs for itself and can be compiled to an exe-file.

The goal is to write different standalone apps, but with the possibility to create a "suite". For example I have apps for notes, todo lists, calculating,... 
and I will give the user the chance to get "all of them in one app" (the apps will display in different tabs for example).

Is this possible? And if yes, please provide some links to a guide or else.

Comment: Microsoft and Adobe have a large suite of software and yet they are separate. I recommend that you make separate applications so that it is easier to keep them up to date. But you can ^^

Comment: Yes, but I don't want have about 10 different windows on my desktop opened. One Window with all application is cleaner and better to use. could you give me a link or something for a guide, tutorial,...?

Comment: No sorry, all tutos for electron is good for you. It's just big app, same code, just other method for develop. 10 apps in same windows, hard for your computer and for navigate.

Comment: sorry, but it isn't hard for the computer nor for navigating. The navigation depends on the user interface design. If you show a list of "modules" as a sidebar, the user can click on the desired module and it will be load the second app at runtime. No overload or performance problems. Nearly every logistic software works like this, because split in modules is a very efficient way to split development overhead.